# Get name of dynamically created div in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I cannot seem to make my javascript .click() method work with my dynamically created divs. In this code I have divs created each under the class name "class1" but my click method does not seem to detect their existence. Here is my code:

```
    <link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function populate() {
        var select = document.getElementById("centres");
        for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.value = i;
            option.text = i;
            select.appendChild(option);
        }
    }

    function divGenerator() {
        var div;
        for (var i = 1; i <= document.getElementById("centres").selectedIndex + 1; i++) {
            div = document.createElement("div");
            div.className = "class1";
            div.innerHTML = "Space " + i;
            div.style.width = "100px";
            div.style.height = "100px";
            div.style.float = "left";
            document.getElementById("container2").appendChild(div);
        }
    }

    function glassLoad() {
        path_to_root_dir = "../../Content/";
        var myBox = new GlassBox();
        myBox.init('myBox', '128px', '62px', 'hidden');
        myBox.apos('170px', '150px');
    }
    // window.onload = populate;

    $(function () {
        $("container2").on("click", ".class1", function () {
            alert("The div was clicked.");
        });
    });

</script>




<div id="container1" style="width: auto; height: 50px;">
    <div id="myBox">Hello World!</div>
    <button style="margin: auto; vertical-align: top; float: left; font-size: 16px;" type="button" onclick="divGenerator();">Generate</button>
    @Html.DropDownList("centres")
</div>
<div id="container2" style="margin: 10px; float: left;" />

<head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Content/javascripts/glassbox/glassbox.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #myBox #myBox_content {
            padding: 2px;
            font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica;
            font-size: 12px;
        }
    </style>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>

    <!--
<a href="javascript:myFunc();">popup</a>
-->
</body>
```

And here is what it returns (taken from google chrome):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <meta name="description" content="Description of your web page goes here." />
    <meta name="keywords" content="Keywords for you web page go here. Each keyword or group of keyword phrases are separated by a comma. Keep this  list short and relevant to the content and title of this specific page." />
    <title>OneEighty Asset Manager
    </title>
    <link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo">
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end #header -->
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- end #menu -->
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="btm">
            <div id="page">
                <h1>
                    <img src="../../Content/Images/1Eighty.png" alt="" style="height: 100px; width: 750px;" /></h1>
                <div id="content">
                    <link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<script type="text/javascript">

    function populate() {
        var select = document.getElementById("centres");
        for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.value = i;
            option.text = i;
            select.appendChild(option);
        }
    }

    function divGenerator() {
        var div;
        for (var i = 1; i <= document.getElementById("centres").selectedIndex + 1; i++) {
            div = document.createElement("div");
            div.className = "class1";
            div.innerHTML = "Space " + i;
            div.style.width = "100px";
            div.style.height = "100px";
            div.style.float = "left";
            document.getElementById("container2").appendChild(div);
        }
    }

    function glassLoad() {
        path_to_root_dir = "../../Content/";
        var myBox = new GlassBox();
        myBox.init('#myBox', '128px', '62px', 'hidden');
        myBox.apos('170px', '150px');
        alert("div clicked");
    }
    // window.onload = populate;



</script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#container2").on("click", ".class1", function () {
            path_to_root_dir = "../../Content/";
            var myBox = new GlassBox();
            myBox.init('#myBox', '128px', '62px', 'hidden');
            myBox.apos('170px', '150px');
            alert("div clicked");
        });
    });
</script>



<div id="container1" style="width: auto; height: 50px;">

    <button style="margin: auto; vertical-align: top; float: left; font-size: 16px;" type="button" onclick="divGenerator();">Generate</button>
    <select id="centres" name="centres"><option>Southdale</option>
<option>Sasolburg</option>
<option>Sandton City</option>
<option>Greenstone</option>
<option>Morningside</option>
<option>Easgate</option>
<option>Bedfordview</option>
<option>Fourways</option>
<option>Linksfield Terrace</option>
<option>Carlton Centre</option>
<option>testcentre1</option>
<option>testcentre2</option>
<option>testcentre3</option>
</select>
</div>
<div id="container2" style="margin: 10px; float: left;" />

<head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Content/javascripts/glassbox/glassbox.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #myBox #myBox_content {
            padding: 2px;
            font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica;
            font-size: 12px;
        }
    </style>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <!--
<a href="javascript:myFunc();">popup</a>
-->
</body>

                </div>
                <!-- end #content -->
                <div style="clear: both;">
                    &nbsp;
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end #page -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <p>
            Copyright (c) 2009 1eightyintra.com. All rights reserved.
        </p>
    </div>
    <!-- end #footer -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you load jQuery properly in your site?

Comment: please use "on" API of jQuery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the element doesn't exist in the DOM on page load, you need to use an event delegate, such as `on`:

```
$(function () {
    $("body").on("click", ".class1", function () {
        alert("The div was clicked.");
    });
});
```

Or for pre-1.7 jQuery, use `delegate`:

```
$(function () {
    $("body").delegate(".class1", "click", function () {
        alert("The div was clicked.");
    });
});
```

Comment: @barnacle.m Yeah that would be best, if you could create a jsfiddle demonstrating the problem that would be even better :)

Comment: Haha I have know idea what that is, I'm new to web development, just started MVC at university actually. I'll post my code in my original post, if that's ok. Thank you!

Comment: @barnacle.m Sure. Just looking at your code, you're not even calling `divGenerator`?

Comment: The button there calls it. It's in a weird place. It does work, creates divs according to the chosen option.

Comment: @barnacle.m Can you post the outputted HTML after the `divGenerator` function has ran? Thinking it might have a slight mistake.

Comment: Have posted the outputted HTML in the main post.

Answer (score 1):

`click` only binds handlers to elements that were present in the DOM when you called it.

Instead, use the [jQuery on method](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").on("click", ".class1", function () {
        alert("The div was clicked.");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to re-apply the click handler to the newly created divs.